# how to change the RadioGroup<String>.builder item text color

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am using   [`group_radio_button`](https://pub.dev/packages/group_radio_button)
and need to change text color (items color) only here am using items are (_statusUpdate)

```
final List<String> _statusUpdate = ["Lunch", "Meeting", "Available"];
```

```
SizedBox(
     height: 150,
     child: Padding(
     padding:
     const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0, left: 60.0, bottom: 20.0),
     child: Column(
     children: <Widget>[
          Transform.scale(
          scale: 1.4,
          child: RadioGroup<String>.builder(
          groupValue: _verticalGroupValue,
          onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
          _verticalGroupValue = value!;
          print("click value : " + value + _verticalGroupValue);
          _saveSwitch();
        }),
        items: _statusUpdate,
        itemBuilder: (item) => RadioButtonBuilder(
        item,
    ),
    activeColor: Colors.green,)
    ,),
   ],
  ),
 ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `textStyle` on `RadioGroup<String>.builder`.

```dart
child: RadioGroup<String>.builder(
  textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.pink),
  groupValue: _verticalGroupValue,
```